# How to support multiple Android versions (4.1 through 7.0)?

Tags: android

**How to make android app run on versions 4.1 through 7.0?**

The following statement was added to the manifest file

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="25"/>
```

However it still only works on 7.0.  What's required to support lower versions too?

Comment: What is your app level `build.gradle` file? Can you share it?

Comment: That is impossible to answer in the abstract. You might want to ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve] and explain exactly what your symptoms are on an older Android device.

Comment: is your app crashing on older versions? if yes, then what's the error?

Comment: add this line in your build.gradle file of your application not in parent build.gradle file
minSdkVersion 17
targetSdkVersion 26

Comment: Your code will have to support android 4.1, so if it doesn't work, then that means that you need to change your code. So like @SarthakMittal said, can you give us the error when you try the app on older versions

Comment: first off all make sure there is no views used which will not run in older versions. if there try to use appCompat of that views. After that try to decrease sdk version

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx622Q1-ksAuUnhMeC1JNi0yT3c

Comment: Unfortunately BluetoothDataExchange has stopped working on lower versions, i got this when try to run,

Comment: If using "external storage" (sdcard) or camera then you need to handle the permissions differently for 6.0 (23) or higher https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-runtime-permissions

Comment: 7.0 is API Level 24 (7.1 is 25).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your app's `Gradle` file with that:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25 // it is recommended to be the same of targetSdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14 // Android 4.1
        targetSdkVersion 25 // Android 7.1
    }
}
```

But maybe you wanna to support Android Oreo to, in this case `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` must be set to `26` (Android always ask to your support the last version)

There is a article which explain in more details `minSdk`, `maxSdk` and `compileSdk`: [link to article](https://www.thedroidsonroids.com/blog/android/compile-min-max-and-target-sdk-versions/)

Comment: Are you certain that compile and target versions must match?

Comment: Not explicitly necessary. `targetSdkVersion` must not be higher than `compileSdkVersion`, they not necessary must be equals. But then maybe you will face some compatibility problems

Comment: Unexpected error while executing: am start -n "com.project.bluetoothdataexchange/com.project.bluetoothdataexchange.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while Launching activity

Comment: For that error I will need more info. I recommend to you open a new question with that error, and, if you succeed to support Android 4.1 - 7.0 in your project, mask this answer as the correct, to close this question

Comment: Instant Run performed a full build and install since
   the installation on the device does not match the local build on disk.